# Combine two vectors into one in R

Tags: r, vector, merge, character, missing-data

I would like to merge two character vectors into one by the following logic:

```
A <- c("005", "NA", "100", "NA")
B <- c("005", "NA", "NA", "257")

C <- c("005", "NA", "100", "257")
```

Let's say I have vector `A` and `B` and I want to merge them in such a way that I get vector `C`, how can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the logic of comparison? Why are those numbers stored as strings? What would be your output if you have two different number in `A` and `B` ?

Comment: These numbers are IDs from two different data frames and stand for a specific brand, respectively. However, there are some missing values (no ID for a given brand). However, I want to keep them. I have two lists (A and B), and I would like to keep list A as it is, but fill the NAs of A up with given values of B, if there are any - in this case "257".

Comment: Note that `"NA"` and `NA` are not the same thing.

Comment: In this case I am talking about NAs -> sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `coalesce` from the `dplyr` package, but notice that you need to replace "NA" to `NA` as in R they are different. Here I convert both `A` and `B` to numeric to achieve this.

```
library(dplyr)

A <- c("005", "NA", "100", "NA")
B <- c("005", "NA", "NA", "257")

A <- as.numeric(A)
B <- as.numeric(B)

coalesce(A, B)
# [1]   5  NA 100 257
```

Comment: I suppose `as.numeric` can be replaced with something like `foo = function(x) replace(x, x == "NA", NA)`

Comment: @d.b I agree with you. The danger of using `as.numeric` along is if there are other characters, such as "below" or "above", they will become `NA`, too, which may not be what the OP wants. But I decided to keep `as.numeric` here as an opportunity to demonstrate the behavior of this function and as a comparison of other answers. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
replace(A, A == "NA", B[A == "NA"])
#[1] "005" "NA"  "100" "257"
```

OR

```
temp = cbind(A, B)
temp[cbind(seq_along(A),
           match(colnames(temp)[max.col(temp != "NA")], colnames(temp)))]
#[1] "005" "NA"  "100" "257"
```

If you have `NA` as opposed to `"NA"`, then change

1. `A == "NA"` to `is.na(A)`
2. `temp != "NA"` to `!is.na(temp)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
C <- A
C[A == "NA"] <- B[A == "NA"]
C
#[1] "005" "NA"  "100" "257"
```